# Debugging with dune

Tags: debugging, ocaml, ocaml-dune

I know of the OCaml debugging tool (first compile with `ocamlc -g <file>`, then run `ocamldebug <output>`) and also the function call tracing feature in the toplevel ([both covered here](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/debug.html)). However, I can't seem to find anything about debug builds with [dune](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Is this possible? Can someone point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: or use tracing https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced-topics.html?highlight=trace#profiling-dune

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `-g` flag is present by default in all build profiles, so the short answer is that you don't need to do anything. As a pro tip, if you want to see what flags are set by default use

```
dune printenv .
```

or for the given building profile, e.g., for `release`,

```
dune printenv --profile release .
```

In a general case, flags are added using `flags`, `ocamlc_flags`, and `ocamlopt_flags` fields that are accepted by `env`, `library`, `executable`, and `executables` stanzas and have the corresponding scopes. If you want your flag to be applied globally you need to add the corresponding flag field to `env` stanza, e.g.,

```
(env
 (release
  (ocamlopt_flags (:standard -O3))))
```

Here `:standard` expands to the standard set of flags.

It is also worth to know that OCaml native executables (the executables compiled to machine code using `ocamlopt`) do not work with `ocamldebug`. You can use either `gdb`, which OCaml supports pretty well or use bytecode executables.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @ivg !

Answer (score 1):

You can build your [dune project in bytecode](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick-start.html#building-a-hello-world-program-in-bytecode) and execute it in [ocamldebug](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/debugger.html).

In a directory of your choice, write this dune file:

```lisp
;; This declares the hello_world executable implemented by hello_world.ml
;; to be build as native (.exe) or bytecode (.bc) version.
(executable
 (name hello_world)
 (modes byte exe))
```

This `hello_world.ml` file:

```ml
print_endline "Hello, world!"
```

And build it with:

```bash
dune build hello_world.bc # (*.bc for bytecode, *.exe for native)
```

The executable will be built as `_build/default/hello_world.bc`.
The executable can then be run in ocamldebug.

```bash
dune build hello_world.bc
ocamldebug _build/default/hello_world.bc
```

**As an important note, ocamldebug version 5.0.0 and below does not support spawning multiple domains for parallel programming.**

And for an execution, the executable can be built and run in a single step with `dune exec ./hello_world.bc`.